Dia (diagrams) edit window super slow in Ubuntu 24.04
I've been using Dia for my diagrams in linux for 20 years or so. It's always been fast and responsive. However since I updated to Ubuntu 24.04, the editing windows of Dia are not responsive at all.
After digging a bit, I found that Dia uses GTK2. Could this be an issue of Ubuntu having worse support for them? Could it be a windows manager issue (i.e. X vs Wayland) ?

Thank you for asking!  I have this same problem.  It is almost unresponsive when I try to view and edit properties.  It is version 0.98.0  The properties window seems to have a new interface.  I will try to install an older version.
